# Short Template in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, templates

I would like to setup my Outlook 2010 to have a quick template available at any time.

For example I want to have the following sentence available at any time in the Outlook.

"Please feel free to contact me if you have any questions or comments. "

Ideally I would like to have a button that I can click on to bring the sentence.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you researched anything about how to do this? A button and a template are two different things. The button would require some VBA. Are you familiar with VBA?

Comment: I did some VBA a year ago... But I would look for a easier solution, since there is a few people asking for the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find it, it is called "Quick Parts".

Import text in Quick Parts

1. OPEN--> NEW E-MAIL
2. In the body on the message type the text you will use as template text
3. Select the text
4. Go to INSERT tab
5. Click on Quick Part drop down
6. Select SAVE SELECTION TO QUICK PART GALLERY
7. Click OK

To use Quick Parts

1. OPEN--> NEW E-MAIL
2. Go to the message body
3. Go to INSERT tab
4. Click on QUICK PARTS
5. Select a quick part

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution may be to save an email message as a template. You can then use it when you need it. To do this you start by creating the message, add the text you want, then save it (don't send). Now copy it from the `Drafts` folder to wherever you want to keep it (desktop). Then delete the message from the `Drafts` folder.

To use the template, open it, complete the message and send.

---

***An alternative;***

To add a line of information to various emails when needed (like you described), I use multiple signatures in Outlook.

You can create a duplicate signatures with slightly different information in each of them for specific purposes. If you aren't familiar with how to create signatures, start here - [Create and add an email message signature.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-and-add-an-email-message-signature-HA010352514.aspx)

Once you have created them, in your email your can right click your signature and chose the one you need.

[image]

Comment: I am looking for a way to store paragraphs, and a quick way to load them into emails. I feel like there should be a better solution to this.